# R Functions: how to pass a response variable as a parameter?

Tags: r, function, glm

When I use functions such as `glm` I need to specify the explicit formula, for example:

```
glm(sales ~ ., data = database)
```

However, when I use this inside of a function, the response variable isn't always "sales". Is there any way I can make the formula parameter of the `glm` function "dynamic" in order to address this issue?

Comment: If all terms enter linearsly, you could use `reformulate`: `glm(reformulate(myControls, yVar), data=database, ...)` where myControls is a character vector of column names and yVar is a character vector of length 1. You can run a `for` loop or `lapply` along a character vector storing multiple values for "yVar".

Answer (score 3):

Something like the following?

```
dynamic <- function(database, response){
    fmla <- as.formula(paste(response, ".", sep = "~"))
    glm(fmla, data = database)
}
```

Then call with the `data.frame` and response variable of your choice.